# What is the specified size of the data type returned by SQL SERVER's SUBSTRING function?

Tags: sql-server

So, my question is, in the case of using the `SUBSTRING` function in SQL SERVER, what will be the size of the data type returned?

So, if it's being used on an `nvarchar(max)`, to truncate a large string down to the first 100 characters, will the return type be `nvarchar(max)` or `nvarchar(100)`?

My specific example is creating a computed column for a table, based on truncating another column (which we don't want to truncate itself).

I'm doing this because i want to use this column in an index, and the data type size is relevant because i can't create an index on an `nvarchar(max)`

So, my code example is:

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable(
...
[Col001] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[TruncCol001To100]  AS SUBSTRING([Col001], 1, 100),
...
)
```

Edit based on comment below: Is the size of the data type specified in this case, and if so, what is the specified size?

Comment: The max size returned by `SUBSTRING([Col001], 0, 100)` is 99.

Comment: OK, but what is the definition of the data type returned? If there is one.

Comment: The returned string is the same type as the specified expression with the exceptions shown in the table. [Quote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SUBSTRING_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) MSDN

Comment: That's not what I was asking. What I want to know is the size of the type. I've since been able to create the index without knowing the specified data type size, but the question is still valid: Is the size specified somewhere, and if so, what is it?

Comment: `substring` in sql server is `1` based, not `0`.

Comment: Good point, will edit

Comment: In your example, the substring will return a nvarchar(10) as my earlier rejected statement indicate

Comment: OK, but where does it say the length will be 100? And not `max`? Or another value?